# Solve $(13x+37)^\frac{1}{3} + (13x -37)^\frac{1}{3} = 2^\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: polynomials

I have to find all the solution of the equation $$(13x+37)^\frac{1}{3} + (13x -37)^\frac{1}{3} = 2^\frac{1}{3}$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Cubing multiple times??

Comment: are you sure you got the signs right ? it's pretty solvable if you change the $+$ into a $-$

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha the given equation actually has no solutions at all.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(13x+37)^{1/3}=A,(13x-37)^{1/3}=B$

$A+B=2^{1/3}$

$A^3-B^3=37+37$

If $A-B=x,74=x^3-3ABx=x^3-\dfrac{3x\{2^{2/3}-x^2\}}4$  as $4AB=(A+B)^2-(A-B)^2$

which is a cubic equation in $x$

Answer (score 2):

Using $a+b+c=0\implies a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$, we get
$$26x-2=-3\cdot2^{1/3}(13^2x^2-37^2)^{1/3}$$
Now cube both sides and solve the cubic.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $u^3=13x+37$ and $b=2^\frac{1}{3}$

$$(13x+37)^\frac{1}{3} + (13x -37)^\frac{1}{3} = 2^\frac{1}{3}$$ becomes 
$$(u^3)^\frac{1}{3} + (u^3 -74)^\frac{1}{3} = b$$
$$u + (u^3 -74)^\frac{1}{3} = b$$
$$(u^3 -74)^\frac{1}{3} = b-u$$

Cubing both sides, we get that
$$u^3 -74=b^3-3b^2u+3bu^2-u^3$$
$$2u^3+3b^2u-3bu^2-(74+b^3)=0$$

Now solve this cubic equation using [Cardano's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).